# Preventing Downward Stacking of Divs

Tags: html, css

If you take this page and reduce the width of the browser window, the divs instead of displaying side by side will stack below each other.  I have tried display: inline-block as well.  I would like it to force the browser to display a scroll bar at the bottom and retain the position of the divs instead, so that you have to scroll left to right to view all content.  I tried adding a container div that has a set height so that it prevents this from happening but this didn't work.

```css
#maincontainer {
 width: 1200px;
 height: 500px;
}
 

#left {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    float: left;
}
    
#middle {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    float: left;    
}
    
#right {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teststyle.css">
    <body>
        <div id = 'maincontainer'>
            <div id = 'left'></div>
            <div id = 'middle'></div>
            <div id = 'right'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of border. Each of the squares is effectively 402px wide because of borders. If you add this css rule: `* {box-sizing:border-box; }` you will get the desired effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/2jwzrzv1/1/

Comment: this resolved the issue, but still unclear as to why effectively increasing the width of the divs by 2px changes stacking behavior.  thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fingers the container you have is 1200px so 402px multiply by 3, means you're just a tiny bit over 1200px, at 1206px, which makes the 3rd div float to the next row.

Comment: Because you gave the container 1200px width and the 3 divs have 402px width each. 402 x 3 = 1206 :) 

This is natural behaviour. If you want the rectangles to be responsive, make them width:33% and this way they should always be 1/3 of the container.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is correct if based on your CSS. There's one small adjustment you want to make that can solve this. Use `box-sizing` so that the borders are counted inside of the box instead of out.

So for your inside divs, use `box-sizing: border-box;`. Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/usmanity/pen/YxyyKY

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you've used pixels to specify the width on the `<div>`. What you're basically telling the browser is that you want it to be this specific size no matter what width the window is. This will naturally cause the `<div>` to stack as they maintain their size.

If you'd like to keep them side-by-side no matter what the browser width is, you'll need to use percentages that add up to 100% depending on the amount of `<div>` you'd like to keep side-by-side.

In your case, the CSS would be:

```
#left {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    float: left;
}

#middle {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of cases I use flex containers, basically if you do this:

```
#maincontainer {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

By doing so all the elements inside the container will be placed next to each other and will try to keep that layout as much as it can.

There are some other features about flex containers, like order, align that are super useful to manipulate positioning.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using float or if you want a scroll bar you can go for overflow.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a fixed width container and set main container to width auto and use scroll-x:

```
<div id = 'maincontainer'>
    <div id="fix-width-container">
        <div id = 'left'></div>
        <div id = 'middle'></div>
        <div id = 'right'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #fix-width-container {
        width: 1206px;
        height: 520px;

    }

    #maincontainer {
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;


    }

    #left {
        width: 400px;
        height: 500px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
        float: left;

    }

    #middle {
        width: 400px;
        height: 500px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
        float: left;


    }

    #right {
        width: 400px;
        height: 500px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
        float: left;

    }
</style>
```

Notice that I added 6px to the fix-width container to hold the borders, I assume that you added them for debugging purposes.